# AppleScript won't keystroke "22.com"?

Tags: macos, applescript

[image]

[image]

I've tried coding it in different ways, but no matter what I do it will not type "22.com".

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Why not add this to your previous AppleScript question at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258415/how-do-i-open-an-application-and-get-it-to-log-in-using-applescript one of our users will likely be able to  kill all of your birds in one stone instead of opening new threads.

Comment: If the first pic contains your real password, I recommend to change the password immediately.

Comment: I just tried `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "22.com"` and it output: `22.com`

Answer (score 1):

I've found that trying to keystroke with a large number of characters is highly unreliable. It doesn't seem to wait for every character to be typed before returning. I'd suggest trying this workaround I've been using:

```
on keystroke_string_(keystr)
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with _character in keystr
            keystroke _character
        end repeat
    end tell
end keystroke_string_
```

That'll iterate through the characters, and press each one manually. I've found that this works nicely with any length of string.